# Inserting new array element using a loop in Java(rookie question)

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So, there is an array `A` that has 20 elements, which was created in the first part of the code. The second part of the code should consist of that very same array, but:

1. A new element should be inserted. That element is 0, and it should be inserted after the first value that is greater than 10.
2. All the remaining values after we insert 0 should move to the right by 1 position.
3. Value of the last element in the array should be deleted, as we inserted 0, and total number of elements cannot exceed 20.

```java
for (i=20-1; i>10; i--) {
    A[i]=A[i-1];
}
A[10]=0;
```

Comment: What info have you looked for online; what "failed"; what "did not work properly"?

Answer (score 1):

The final loop works. You are printing the array `A` before your changes. Print the array again (after the final loop) at the end of the main method and you will see it.